# Dynamic styles aren't being applied

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a menu that I've built styles for and have some menu options that should not be shown to non-admin users.  I've put a link to an asp.net page as a dynamic style.  Here is the code:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Styles/DynamicStyle.aspx" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

the source of DynamicStyle.aspx:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators"))
        {
            StringBuilder oSb = new StringBuilder();

            oSb.AppendLine(".restricted");
            oSb.AppendLine("{");
            oSb.AppendLine("display: none;");
            oSb.AppendLine("}");

            Response.Write(oSb.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

I have verified that it does emit the proper CSS.

here is a snip of the code that should be hiding the button:

```
 <li><a href="events.aspx">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="industries.aspx">Industries</a></li>
                <li class="restricted"><a href="institutions.aspx">Institutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="jobgroups.aspx">Job Groups</a></li>
                <li><a href="jobtitles.aspx">Job Titles</a></li>
```

In Mozilla's inspector, it does not list the restricted as having been applied.

I have never tried to do this this way but have seen it done and am wondering what I am missing?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the target element is already rendered when you write to the response stream then it will not be changed. If you want to make a CSS change at runtime you'll need to query the DOM w/ javascript.

Comment: Why don't you just put `.restricted` into the css file rather than rendering with c#? Your `li` is adding the class correctly so that would seem the easier way to accomplish it. Otherwise, jquery would seem the more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning the correct content type for CSS (it's returning type of `text/html` instead of `text/css`). Your code would work if you add `Response.ContentType = "text/css";`:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/css";
Response.Write(oSb.ToString());
Response.End();
```

But the real problem is you are simply "hiding" links that people shouldn't see... but if they view the page source, they can still see them. A better option is to not send those links to the client at all. One option is:

```
<li id="_admin1" runat="server"><a href="institutions.aspx">Institutions</a></li>
```

and then in your code behind:

```
_admin1.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators");
```

Now the html for that `<li>` won't even be sent to the client unless they are in the correct role.